# Failed to download repository information from lynis and dell

Tags: 18.04, repository

Why does this appear? I hadn't had this problem on 16.04, now on 18.04 I have it. If I dosable it since there is no release file, how will I find out when they publish a release file?

```
E:The repository 'https://packages.cisofy.com/community/lynis/deb bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists bionic-dell Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: The error "...does not have a Release file" usually means there are no packages for this release in the repository, which implies it has not been updated. If all works as expected, just remove them. Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: you might just need to re-add the ppa from this page: https://packages.cisofy.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just need to re-add the PPA:

If you want the cisco PPA:

```
https://packages.cisofy.com/
```

Not sure if you wan to use customer or community ppa from above, so you will have to link to your desired one and follow the directions there.

Comment: There aren't any packages or updates in ppa:cisofy/lynis. It's an empty PPA.